# Dbt macro does not applied for location table property

Tags: airflow, dbt

Consider model config:

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental',
    format='parquet',
    unique_key = 'id',
    incremental_strategy='delete+insert',
    partitioned_by=['day(updated_at)', 'day(created_at)', 'site_id'],
    properties= {
      "format": "'PARQUET'",
      "location": "{{this}}"
    },
    post_hook=[
      "ALTER TABLE {{this}} EXECUTE optimize(file_size_threshold => '{{var('maintenance')['sile_size']}}')",
      "ALTER TABLE {{this}} EXECUTE expire_snapshots(retention_threshold => '{{var('maintenance')['snapshots']['period']}}')",
      "ALTER TABLE {{this}} EXECUTE remove_orphan_files(retention_threshold => '{{var('maintenance')['orphan_files']['period']}}')"
    ],
  )
}}
```

After compilation, I got:

```
create table my_table
    WITH (
        format = 'PARQUET',
        location = {{this}})
as (
```

So no interpolation for location at all. Any ideas why and how to fix?